# Select and Insert in the same query NODE JS with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a string with the query below, in the MYSQL workbench works fine, but when is called from a string in node query, that me return syntax error on the select, can anyone help me?

```
INSERT INTO mdl_feedback_completed (
feedback
,userid
,timemodified
,random_response
,anonymous_response
)
VALUES (
:feedback
,:userid
,:timemodified
,:random_response
,:anonymous_response
);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS IdCompleted;
```

Comment: Can you put your error message in the question?

Comment: Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"error":{"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","errno":1064,"sqlMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select 1' at line 4","sqlState":"42000","index":0,"sql":"\r\nINSERT INTO mdl_feedback_completed (feedback, userid, timemodified, random_response, anonymous_response)\r\nVALUES (1546, 11599, 1529680717214, 0, 0)\r\n\r\nSelect 1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}},"status":500

Comment: Put it in the question not as comment

Answer (score 0):

To query multiple statements on mysql using node needs

var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});